# Sum of arrays using recursive function

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Am a php developer and i have studied about recursive function and i coded to find the sum of elements in an array with recursive function but i got the error.

## THE CODE WHICH I GOT FROM INTERNET

```
$example = array(10,20,30);


function sum_array($array) {


$total = 0;
foreach ($array as $element) {
    if(is_array($element)) {
        $total += sum_array($element);
    } else {
        $total += $element;
    }
}
return $total;


}

echo sum_array($example); // Outputs 60
```

## MY CODE

```
<?php
 $example = array(10,20,30);

function add_me($arr) {

  if($arr==0) {

    return $arr;



 } 
  return add_me($arr[0]+$arr[1]+$arr[2]);



}
```

The first code which i found from the internet works well but in case of my code it gives an error. When i called it using `echo add_me($example);` it forms an error .

Can you please tell me why it is like that ..Any help would be appreciated ..Thanks.

Comment: It must be `if($arr==0) {` . You don't have `$array` defined anywhere , so why use it ? _This solves just the syntactical problem issue.._

Comment: i just edited and the problem still persists..

Comment: What do you think `if ($arr==0)` means?

Comment: First of all, you are not at all calling your function.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky i mean if array is 0 ..ie null

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran didnt get you ?

Comment: @user3550798: What's the point of this function? Why can't you simply use `array_sum()`? Are you trying to make `array_sum()` recursive?

Comment: It would certainly help if you tell us *which* error you get.

Comment: You're code has so many issues... first, you want to call it with an array, and that array will always have 3 values in it. Second, you have no escape for the function once you do call it unless it errors out.. There's nothing functional about the code you wrote, really.

Comment: @AmalMurali yes ..i want to make it recrusive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for recursion on arrays, you could use  [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) class , also see [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) class

**A simple illustration** (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array/1320259#1320259)):

```
<?php
$a = array(1,2,array(3,4, array(5,6,7), 8), 9);
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a));
foreach($it as $v) {
    $new_arr[] = $v;
}
echo array_sum($new_arr); // "prints" 45
```

Comment: Just a note: You don't need to call `array_sum()` again. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3778104/1438393).

Comment: @AmalMurali, Come on I know that. The `$a` array is actually flattened to `$new_arr` so that the OP can use it for other purposes too. ;)

Comment: I'm sure you know that. But I thought the OP wasn't really familiar with recursion, so that was more of an FYI comment.

Comment: @AmalMurali, I _intentionally_ did that , since after sometime OP may come and ask how to add the first four elements , last four elements , third and seventh element.. as such. So putting it inside an array would be more easier. Also, since OP is familiar with `array_sum()` , I used that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to create a recursive function, use the following:

```
function sum_array($array)
{
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        // if the value itself is an array
        // recurse further: call the function again
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $sum = $sum + sum_array($value);
        }
        // if the value is not an array,
        // simply add it to $sum
        else {
            $sum = $sum + $value;
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}

echo sum_array([3, 4, [5,6], 8]); // => 26
```

[`is_array()`](http://php.net/is_array) checks if the value is an array and if so, call the function again. If the value is not an array, the value is simply added to `$sum`. At the end, `$sum` is returned.

---

This can be done in multiple ways. Here are some:

**Using [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive):**

```
function sum_array($array) {
    $sum = 0;
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($v) use (&$sum) {
        $sum += $v;
    });
    return $sum;
}

echo sum_array([3, 4, [5,6], 8]); // => 26
```

**Using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce):**

```
function callback($v, $w) {
    return $v + (is_array($w) ? array_reduce($w, __FUNCTION__) : $w);
}

echo array_reduce([3, 4, [5,6], 8], 'callback'); // => 26
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_sum($array)` PHP function

Comment: yes i know ..and i did it to learn about recrusion method in php

Comment: @user3550798 - factorial is good example to learn recursive method :)

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't really do anything with your code to make it functional, I figured I'd explain the function you got from the internet:

```
//Set sample data
$example = array(10,20,30);
function sum_array($array) {
    //first time called, we start at 0
    $total = 0;
    //Loop through each value in the array
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        //If the value is another array, we use recursion
        if(is_array($element)) {
            //using the recursion, we send the array to this function and add to total
            $total += sum_array($element);
        } else {
            //value was not an array, but scalar, add to total
            $total += $element;
        }
    } // Go to next value
    //Give the total back to asker
    return $total;
}
echo sum_array($example); // Outputs 60
```

That's the same code you had with comments added for each line. For an example of how it works with the `$example` array, it would go:

```
sum_array([10,20,30])
$total = 0
$element = 10
$total += 10  //10
$element = 20
$total += 20 //30
$element = 30
$total += 30 //60

return $total //60
```

With the example data, no recursion happens at all, it would if you had an array as one of the values, ie `[10, [5, 2], 20]` and then it would go like:

```
sum_array([10,[5,2],20])
$total = 0
$element = 10
$total += 10  //10
$element = [5, 2]
sum_array([5,2])
    $total_1 = 0
    $element_1 = 5
    $total_1 += 5 //5
    $element_1 = 2
    $total_1 += 2  //7
    return $total_1 //7
$total += $total_1 //17
$element = 20
$total += 20 //37
return $total //37
```

Hopefully that will help aid you in understanding recursion.

Comment: so in the line "$total += sum_array($element);" the whole array elements are added to $total ...right ?

Comment: The whole inner-array. In my expanded example, that would be the `[5, 2]`

Comment: @user3550798: `$foo += $bar` is a shorter way of writing `$foo = $foo + $bar`. In this case, it means `$total = $total + sum_array($element)` (where `$element` is `[5, 2]`).

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum(array $input) {
    #Base case
    if ( count($input) == 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( is_array( $input[0] ) ) {
        return $input[0][0] + sum( array_merge_recursive( array_slice($input, 1), array_slice($input[0], 1) ) );
    }
    else {
        return $input[0] + sum( array_slice( $input, 1) );    
    }
}

print sum([10, 20, 30]); //60

print sum([10, [10,10], [20,10]]); //60
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15066593)