# Value from Array Inside Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Let say I have a function inside a controller of a CI

```
    public function mr_printing () {

    $code = $_POST ['item_id'] ;
    $count = count($code) ;
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
      $idline = $code [$i] ;
      $new ['item'] = $this -> model_prcsys -> get_line_data (md5(base64_decode($idline))) ;
      $arr = $this -> model_prcsys -> get_sum_received ($new ['item'] ['pr_line_id']) ;
      $sum = ($arr) ;
      print_r($sum);echo "<br><br>";
    }
}
```

by that, I have output :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [qty_incoming] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [qty_incoming] => 2 ) )

Array ( [0] => Array ( [qty_incoming] => 3 ) )
```

From the first array, I need to get value from SUM for every array. In another word, I need output like this:

```
7

3
```

Anyone, please?

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777995/php-array-recursive-sum

Comment: `array_sum(array_column($arr, 'qty_incoming'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
echo array_sum(array_column($arr, 'qty_incoming'));
```

Comment: $arr = $this -> model_prcsys -> get_sum_received ($new ['item'] ['pr_line_id']) ;
$sum = array_sum($arr) ;
print_r($arr);echo "<br><br>";
print_r($sum);echo "<br><br>";

have value:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [qty_incoming] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [qty_incoming] => 2 ) )

0

Array ( [0] => Array ( [qty_incoming] => 3 ) )

0

Comment: this will give 0 ans

Comment: Thanks @  user1234

Comment: Thanks, Rakesh ..
It saved my day ... :)
never thought array_column

Answer (score 1):

1)fetch the particular column from multidimentional array using  [array_colum](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_column.asp).

2)sum using  [array_sum](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sum.asp).

```
$total =  array_sum(array_column($array_values, 'qty_incoming'));
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $sum += $item['qty_incoming'];
}
echo $sum;
```