# Using recursion to build navigation

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I'm building navigation for a site and for the life of me I can't figure out recursion. I have all my data stored via MySQL using this design:

[image]

I've read several links on how recursion works and I must be slow because it's difficult for me to grasp. I've tried to write something and I know it is not even close to what I really need, but it's a start:

PDO

```
public function viewCategories()
{
    $viewSQL = "SELECT * FROM categories";  
    try
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=store','root','');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $categoryVIEW = $pdo->prepare($viewSQL);
        $categoryVIEW->execute();
        $array = $categoryVIEW->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $categoryVIEW->closeCursor();
        $json = json_encode($array);
        return $json;
    }
    catch(PDOexception $e)
    {
        return $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}
```

Recursion

```
$return = json_decode($category->viewCategories(),true);

function buildNavigation($json)
{
    foreach($json as $item)
    {
        if($item['category_id'] === $item['parent'])
        {
            print('<li>'.$item['category_name'].'</li>');
            if($item['category_id'] === $item['parent'])
            {
                print('<li>match'.$item['category_name'].'</li>');
                buildNavigation($json);
            }
        }
}
buildNavigation($return);
```

as expected this will never enter the condition. I did try to figure this out on my own since this is a good thing to have knowledge of, but I guess it's beyond my mental capacity :(

Thanks for having a look :)

**UPDATE**

I know this has been answered already, but is there a way I can do this to build an associative array? I have been playing around with a function that ALMOST works for me that I got from **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776798/php-array-recursion)**, but it adds an extra array that I do NOT want.

**Method**

```
private function buildCategories($array,$parent)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $row)
    {
        if($row['parent'] == $parent)
        {
            $result[$row['category_name']] = $this->buildCategories($array,$row['category_id']);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$json = json_encode($this->buildCategories($array,NULL));
return $json;
```

I want this:

```
{"reloading":{"components","presses and dies","tumblers & scales","tools & accessories","shotshell reloading"}
```

but what I get is this:

```
{"reloading":{"components":[],"presses and dies":[],"tumblers & scales":[],"tools & accessories":[],"shotshell reloading":[]}
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive functions, so it is not well suited to this adjacency list model of storing hierarchical data. You ought to consider restructuring your data to use either nested sets or a transitive closure table.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/623041) for more information.

Comment: Hey eggyal, can't I accomplish this through PHP rather than MySQL? I figured I could iterate through my PDO output?

Comment: Well, yes you can.  But it's very inefficient...

Comment: Hm, that's good to know. I guess I'm traveling down the wrong path.

Comment: Recursion means that the function *calls itself* from within the function, typically depending on certain conditions.  Your `buildNavigation` function calls `buildCategories` - where's the code for that function?

Comment: Do you only have 2 levels of navigation? If so, you don't need recursion.

Comment: Whoops, forgive me. I wrote the wrong function name. I will update, thanks.

Comment: @ Maxime Morin - Yep, all I have is one parent and one child.

Comment: Well there could be infinite amount of children, but the children will only have one parent.

Comment: That loop/recursion thing going on there looks pretty infinite too.. The function calls itself with the same argument.

Comment: why you fold same condition  ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's an example with recursion.

```
function buildNavigation($items, $parent = NULL)
{
    $hasChildren = false;
    $outputHtml = '<ul>%s</ul>';
    $childrenHtml = '';

    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        if ($item['parent'] == $parent) {
            $hasChildren = true;
            $childrenHtml .= '<li>'.$item['category_name'];         
            $childrenHtml .= buildNavigation($items, $item['category_id']);         
            $childrenHtml .= '</li>';           
        }
    }

    // Without children, we do not need the <ul> tag.
    if (!$hasChildren) {
        $outputHtml = '';
    }

    // Returns the HTML
    return sprintf($outputHtml, $childrenHtml);
}

print buildNavigation($items);
```

That script produces the following output :

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu 2.1</li>
            <li>Sub Menu 2.2</li>
            <li>Sub Menu 2.3
                <ul>
                    <li>Sub Menu 2.2.1</li>
                    <li>Sub Menu 2.2.2</li>
                    <li>Sub Menu 2.2.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: THERE IT IS! Nice job! I'm not sure if I will ever understand this, but thank you very much :)

Comment: Quick question, would it be better to do this in my class then pass it formatted?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by formatted, but the buildNavigation function should be in a MenuHelper, HTMLHelper or somewhere close to your view (HTML).  I wouldn't put this in a model or data object.

Comment: Great awnser @MaximeMorin only i have one question, how can you seperate the parent <ul> from the children <ul>. For example to have a different css class on the parent?

Comment: @JarnovanRhijn Where we initialize the `$outputHtml` variable, you can check if `$parent == null` and change the content of `$outputHtml` accordingly.  For example, if `$parent == null` then `<ul class="parent-class">%s</ul>` else `<ul class="child-class">%s</ul>`.  This should only mark the root UL with a parent class.  I haven't tested this, let me know how it goes.

Comment: working for me....was tired...finally google shown ur question url....hats off to u

Answer (score 0):

I have the same above code with little bit modification, so that a user can apply different css on each level of menu, now its showing classes of sub menu like child-class1 when its in 1st sub menu , and it will show child-class2 when its in 2nd sub menu and so on...

```
  <?php
 function buildNavigation($items, $parent = NULL, $n=NULL)
    {
$hasChildren = false;
if ($parent == NULL)
{
    $level=0;
    $outputHtml = '<ul class="parent-class">%s</ul>';
}
else
{
    if($n==NULL)
    {
        $level=1;
    }
    else
    {
        $level=$n;
    }
    $outputHtml = '<ul class="child-class'.$level.'">%s</ul>';  
} 
$childrenHtml = '';
foreach($items as $item)
{
    if ($item['parent'] == $parent) {
        $hasChildren = true;
        $childrenHtml .= '<li><a href="/'.$item['slug'].'">'.$item['ptitle'].'</a>';
        $next = ++$level;
        $childrenHtml .= buildNavigation($items, $item['pageid'],$next);         
        $childrenHtml .= '</li>';           
    }
}

// Without children, we do not need the <ul> tag.
if (!$hasChildren) {
    $outputHtml = '';
}

// Returns the HTML
return sprintf($outputHtml, $childrenHtml);
}
echo  buildNavigation($ppages);
?>
```

it will show out put like this

```
    <ul class="parent-class">
      <li>
        <a href="http://example.com/page-1">page 1</a>
           <ul class="child-class1">
              <li>
                 <a href="http://example.com/this-is-child-page">this is child page</a>
                  <ul class="child-class2">
                     <li>
                        <a href="http://example.com/child-of-child">child of child</a>                 </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

I would like to thanks Mr @Maxime Morin.