# Build an associative array from parent child relationship

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I've been playing around with a function that ALMOST works for me that I got from **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776798/php-array-recursion)**, but it adds an extra array that I do NOT want. The information is stored in my database like so:

[image]

**Method**

```
private function buildCategories($array,$parent)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $row)
    {
        if($row['parent'] == $parent)
        {
            $result[$row['category_name']] = $this->buildCategories($array,$row['category_id']);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$json = json_encode($this->buildCategories($array,NULL));
return $json;
```

I want this:

```
{"reloading":{"components","presses and dies","tumblers & scales","tools & accessories","shotshell reloading"}
```

but what I get is this:

```
{"reloading":{"components":[],"presses and dies":[],"tumblers & scales":[],"tools & accessories":[],"shotshell reloading":[]}
```

**NOTE:** I've asked a similar question, but it was NOT to build an associative array. Since it was not like I originally asked I figured another thread was required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get this:

```
{"reloading":["components","presses and dies","tumblers & scales","tools & accessories","shotshell reloading"]}
```

Code:

```
private function buildCategories($array,$parent) 
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $row) {
        if($row['parent'] == $parent) {
            if ($row['parent'] == NULL) {
                $result[$row['category_name']] = $this->buildCategories($array,$row['category_id']);
            } else {
                $result[] = $row['category_name'];
            }
        }
    }
    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: Apparently I need to give this coding crap up .. I spent 3 hours trying to get this on my own and you nailed it in less than 5 minutes. Awesome, thank you!